# how to create a service in services.msc using ant script(build.xml)?

Tags: tomcat, ant, build.xml

I need a build.xml in which if we execute the script it should create a service (say Apache) in service.msc

Also in the same script i need to set the JVM environvent variables .
Here's the code I've tries so far:

```
<project name="services" > 
  <property environment="env"> 
  <property name="env.JAVA_HOME" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"/> 
  <property name="env.CATALINA_HOME" value="C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin"/> 
  <property/> 
  <target name="create" > 
    <exec dir="C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin" executable="cmd.exe"> 
      <arg line="/c sc create "apacheservice" binPath= "C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin" 
    </exec> 
  <target/>
```

please give your comments.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you do so far ?

Comment: I am new to this field some how i managed to write the below script.I dont know whether this will work or not 

<project name="services" >
<property environment="env">
<property name="env.JAVA_HOME" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"/> 
<property name="env.CATALINA_HOME" value="C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin"/> 
<property/>
<target name="create" >
<exce dir="C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin" executable="cmd.exe">
<arg line="/c sc create "apacheservice" binPath= "C:\.....\.....\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin"
</exec>
<target/>